# jquery validation plugin: "b is undefined"

Tags: jquery, validation, jeditable

I'm using:

- jQuery validation plug-in 1.6
  *
- http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

with the latest version of jQuery.

I'm also using  Jeditable 1.7.1

When I "inline edit" an item and press OK or Cancel or even when typing in the text field or when clicking outside of the edit inline element, it gives me a very non-informative JS-error: "b is undefined" and it points towards the jquery validation file

```
b is undefined
delegate()jquery.v...ck.1.6.js (line 15)
anonymous()jquery.v...ck.1.6.js (line 15)
anonymous(Object originalEvent=Event keyup type=keyup)jquery.min.js (line 19)
anonymous()
```

Any ideas on how I can find what's wrong here?

jEditable seems to work just fine on another page where I'm not using the validation plugin

Comment: post code please to help with the problem

Comment: The "non-informative error" arises because you're using a minified Javascript library, which (among other thing) shortens variable names and removes comments and extra white space.

Comment: Andrzej, how do I recognize answers? I'm new around here!

Comment: Just take a look at your previous answers, and click the big "V" (which is just left each of the answers you received) on the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: thanks guys, I voted for the best answers in all of my previous questions. I didn't notice that before. Sorry!

Comment: the problem only exists with the Packed version of the validation plugin. Development version works like a charm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the problem only exists with the
>   Packed version of the validation
>   plugin. Development version works like
>   a charm... – Jorre 8 secs ago

Then its probably an issue with the packing of the plugin. Try repacking it yourself with one of the many tools - or just use the dev or minified version. Id alos file a bug report with the devs.